# linear layout weight inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

what I am  trying to do is some thing like this.

[image]

image one

No matter which device is it. It should display ony four rows on the screen and later user can scroll to see other rows

I am using veritical linearlayout weight to achieve this,But it does not happening the way i am trying to achieve this. its give me screen like this when i add more rows

[image]

image two

below is my layout xml which gives screen as image one but adding more rows gives image two view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightGray"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:weightSum="4"

                >


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/abulation"
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/wudu_96" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/masjid"
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/masjid_96" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/restroom"
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/restroom_96" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dressing"
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/dressing_96" />

                    <ImageButton
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Favourite"
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/favourite_96"
                        android:onClick="random"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon"
                        android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know i am doing wrong thing to achieve this . Please help me how can i get the view i want .

Comment: why you not using recycler view with grid.? i think its better way to achieve this

Comment: Try this way -- In the first linearLayout (android:weightSum="1.0") and in the ones inside (android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25")   -- see if that gives you 4 equal rows

Comment: are these categories static?

Comment: IMO, this isn't a matter of `layout_weight`, you need to find available screen height, divide it by 4 and then apply that height to each of the `LinearLayout` at runtime.

Comment: its vertical so try (android:layout_height="0dp")

Comment: yes they are static

Comment: adding screen height at run time will be good idea to add height to each icon ?

Comment: look i updated my question . It gives image one view by the xml i shared

Comment: @FaisalAhmed If you need that kind of an arrangement, you need to provide height at runtime. Its shouldn't have any visible effects of the performance and its a normal practice. Come to think of it, it should be a performance gain mainly because you'd be getting rid of `layout_weight`

Comment: @Shaishav , I am new to android and making my first app . This idea came to my mind but i thought it will not be good programming practice to add height at runtime according to screen size of mobile . Is this only way i can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have wrapped your view in one more parent LinearLayout in ScrollView that might just be the reason for your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightGray"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:weightSum="4"

                >


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/abulation"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#FF0F0F" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/masjid"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#D0060F" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/restroom"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#1F0F0F" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dressing"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#FF0F0F" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#1F0F0F"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Favourite"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#D0060F"
                        android:onClick="random"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#D0060F" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#1F0F0F" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#FF0F0F" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#1F0F0F" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#D0060F" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#FF0F0F" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Hope it helps.!**

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do: Firstly we get rid of `android:weightSum` property from the main vertical `LinearLayout` and the `android:layout_weight` from each of the horizontal `LinearLayout`. We also need to set `id` to our vertical `LinearLayout` as `android:id=@+id/mainContainerLL`. This is the sample layout that i derived for testing from your layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rowContainerLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="1dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"

                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"

                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"

                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"

                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"

                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Now, for the java coding part: We use a `ViewTreeObserver` to get height at runtime (observer gives us a callback when views are about to be drawn and their heights are calculated so, we need that). There, we set height to each of our horizontal `LinearLayout`:

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rowContainerLL);
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

    viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

            View child;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
            final int viewHeight = linearLayout.getHeight() / 4;

            for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                child = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = viewHeight;

                child.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have used getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(); and and dividing by 4 to metric.height gives me height . It works good and solved my issue . Can you tell me what the is difference between my code and your code?

Comment: @FaisalAhmed I did try that too but, I guess I was getting slightly inexact values do to Status Bar/Notification Bar so, I reverted to this. Also, whenever I use `ViewTreeObserver` and have to deal with view containers spanning the entire screen, I prefer to simply call `getHeight()` since, I'm assured the value would be legitimate (due to `ViewTreeObserver`) and should return exactly the space available to draw. But, I guess what method we use shouldn't really make much difference.

Comment: So I Hope I did it in a right way . And your suggestion was really help full thanks alot